# More than 2 languages to choose in PHP with cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I have a code that allows to choose language for website and save what you've chosen to cookie. Also it is also gets local browser language and sets to webiste as default. But i had only two languages **Russian** and **English**. 
And I wanted to add two more languages. But they don't work. Why? Any Solution?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

if ( !empty($_GET['language']) )
{
    $_COOKIE['language'] = $_GET['language'] === 'en' ? 'en' : 'ru';
}
elseif (empty($_COOKIE['language']))
{
    $_COOKIE['language'] = $lang;
}


setcookie('language', $_COOKIE['language']);


if ( $_COOKIE['language'] == "en")
{
   $language = 'en';
}
elseif ( $_COOKIE['language'] == "es")
{
  $language = 'es';
}
elseif ( $_COOKIE['language'] == "zh")
{
  $language = 'zh';
}
else
{
   $language = 'ru';
}

$xml = simplexml_load_file("language.xml") or die("1YOU!");

$restore = $xml->restore->$language;
$set_up = $xml->set_up->$language;
$intro = $xml->intro->$language;
$intro_all = $xml->intro_all->$language;
$s_title = $xml->s_title->$language;
$advcash_login = $xml->advcash_login->$language;
$advcash_fee = $xml->advcash_fee->$language;
$advcash_amount = $xml->advcash_amount->$language;
$payeer_amount = $xml->payeer_amount->$language;
$payeer_fee = $xml->payeer_fee->$language;
$payment_send = $xml->payment_send->$language;
$deposit = $xml->deposit->$language;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should be well refactored like this:

```
$allow_langs = array('en', 'es', 'zh', 'ru');
$browser_lang = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2));
$language = (isset($_COOKIE['language']) ? $_COOKIE['language'] : $browser_lang);
if (isset($_GET['language'])) {
  $language = $_GET['language'];
}
if (!in_array($language, $allow_langs, true))
  $language = 'en'; //fallback for invalid lang
setcookie('language', $language);
//do your xml loading on $language var
```

Comment: Thanks! Edited code a bit, so if no language in cookies, sets browser language

Comment: Instead of the suggested edit it should be $browser_lang instead of '' after the inline if, changing the fallback is dangerous because the Accept Language is an untrusted user input in HTTP Header, I edited the post to include the correct code. The in_array check is only for invalid langs that are not present in the array